# using difference_type in BOOST foreach

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, distance

is there a possibility to use difference_type with std::distance in the BOOST_FOREACH loop?

```
#define foreach_ BOOST_FOREACH
class iObj { /* some def and impl */ };
typedef set<iObj*> iSet;

int main() {
    iSet *iobjs = new iSet();

    // fill set with integers
    for( int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        iobjs->insert( new iObj(i+1+i*2) );
    }

    // output content of set
    cout << "print objects ASC" << endl;
    for( iSet::const_iterator oIt = iobjs->begin();
         oIt != iobjs->end(); ++oIt) {
        iSet::difference_type oIndex = std::distance( iobjs->begin(), oIt );
        if( oIndex < 50 ) {
            cout << " #" << oIndex << ": " << **oIt << endl;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // output with BOOST
    cout << "print objects ASC" << endl;
    foreach_( iObj *o, *iobjs ) {
        cout << *o << endl;
        // no access of index?
    }

    delete iobjs;
    return 0;
}
```

it is more convenient to display e.g. the first 50 entries of a big set, not the whole content and with std::distance it is not necessary to insert a new counter var and increment it by myselfe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know the loop iteration from within the body of a `BOOST_FOREACH` loop? No, you can't do that. You can't do it with a C++11 range-based `for` loop, either. For this purpose, the ordinary `for` loop is best. (And please, please, please stop using `BOOST_FOREACH`. C++11's range-based `for` is the final word on the subject.)

I should also point out that your code is needlessly inefficient. `std::set`'s iterators are not random-access, so `std::distance` is O(N). Far better is to keep a separate loop counter, and simply increment it each time through the loop.

Also, your code is leaking memory. Although you are deleting the `std::set` you have `new`'ed, you're not deleting all the `iObj` objects you've `new`'ed. It doesn't seem like there is any need to be dynamically allocating anything in the code you've shown. Try just storing objects by value instead of `new`'ing them, and use a local `std::set` stack variable too. You'll save yourself a world of trouble.

Comment: yes, i've noticed that destructor of iObj-Object in `std::set` was not called. But some implementations require storing pointer in a container. How can i force call dtor of stored objects when deleting container?

Comment: If you're using a C++11 compiler and standard library, use `std::set<std::unique_ptr<iObj>>`. Otherwise, use `std::set<boost::shared_ptr<iObj> >`.